# writing two integers $a \le b$ as products of $n$ integers $\prod{a_i}$ and $\prod{b_i}$ such that $a_i \le b_i$ with the greatest $n$

Tags: arithmetic, discrete-optimization

Let $a$ and $b$ be two positive integers such that $a \le b$.

I want to find a pair of n-uplets of ${\mathbb{N}^{*}}^n$ : $(a_i)_{1 \le i \le n}$ and  $(b_i)_{1 \le i \le n}$ for the greatest n possible

such that  :

a) $a = \prod_{1 \le i \le n}{a_i}$, $b = \prod_{1 \le i \le n}{b_i}$

b) $\forall 1 \le i \le n , a_i \le b_i $

It seems a good idea to decompose $a$ and $b$ as products of prime numbers and to remark that the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are sub-products of those prime numbers. As far as there are common prime numbers in both decomposition, we can add an $a_i=b_i$ equal to that common number, then we are left with the same problem but where $a$ and $b$ have no common prime numbers in their decomposition.

**Context of this problem :**

I want to create injection between  elements of two "tensors" (I guess that is the correct name) with the simpliest "rules" possible.

ex : $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\times\{1,2\} \times\{1,2,3,4\} \leftarrow  \{1,2,3\}\times\{1,2,3\} \times\{1,2,3\} $

There are $b=40$ elements in the first set and $a=27$ in the second.

if $a_1 = 3$, $a_2 = 9$, $b_1=4$ and $b_2=10$, I can "decompose" my injection into

An injection $I_1$ between $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$

An injection $I_2$ between $\{1,2,3,4,5\} \times \{1,2\}$ and $\{1,2,3\} \times \{1,2,3\}$

the final injection being $I(i,j,k) = (I_1(k),I_2(i,j))$

Comment: Any restrictions on $a_i$ and $b_i$? Otherwise I can just include lots of $1$'s.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Is there any reason to imagine that it has a pleasant answer?   Just to say, it looks non-trivial just to find the least factor of an integer which exceeds some lower bound (a much easier problem no?).

Comment: I added some context and the constraints of $a_i \gt 1$

Comment: Interesting ;  btw, in your example the arrow should go from right to left